# in Eclipse, Commit option is not visible

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, am not able to see the option called Commit in Team. Please help is there any settings to get that option. Please do let me know. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the project Open.  Open first, then right click for Team and Commit.

Then when you right click on the Repository in Git Repository view or the Project in Package Explorer view, you will see the option in Team.

If you have not connected to the remote repository or have no repositories locally, then I think you also have the same problem.  Connect to or select a repository.

Your project is open, so you may be offline at the point you took the image or perhaps the repository is not connected.

In the Window menu tab, select Show View and then select Other and then Git.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install git integration plugin from marketplace and then set up your git account